# An error when trying to change Image workflow

Tags: plone

In short, when I go into Site Setup -> Types and try and change the workflow for Images from "No Workflow" to any other workflow, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module plone.app.controlpanel.types, line 165, in __call__
  Module zope.event, line 31, in notify
  Module zope.component.event, line 24, in dispatch
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module plone.app.discussion.browser.controlpanel, line 181, in notify_configuration_changed
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'forInterface'
```

I suspect the way we setup this Plone instance caused the issue. We have a 4.0.8 install (Staging) where we did our initial site construction. We setup another 4.0.8 install for production. Ran a backup on Staging and copied the Staging backup files and blobstorage over to Production. Production worked fine; appeared to be a perfect clone of Staging.

Later, we wanted to move to 4.1.1, so we created another install on 4.1.1 and repeated the above process from Production to our new instance. After a day of testing, it appears to work. Cool, we have a 4.1.1 Production box now. Week later, users want Images to operate under the same workflow (Intranet/Extranet) as all the other content and that's when I ran into the error.

I *can* change the workflow through the ZMI portal_workflow tool without any apparent problems.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [product code](http://svn.plone.org/svn/plone/plone.app.discussion/trunk/plone/app/discussion/browser/controlpanel.py),  It seems that when you change the contenttype's workflow the p.a.discussion product tries to update its configuration but in your instance fails to retrieve the registry.

As a fast solution you could try to force the inclusion of the registry by adding in a zcml of one of your products this code:

```
<include package="plone.app.registry" />
```

then:

1- go to zmi -> your site and check if in your plone site exists an item called "portal_registry"

2- go to zmi -> your site -> tab "Components" and check if exists this registration:

```
<utility interface="plone.registry.interfaces.IRegistry"
         object="portal_registry" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, could solve it by importing the steps 'Manage the configuration registry' and '   Plone caching' of the profile 'Configuration registry'.