# Cannot change the Type Settings in Site Setup

Tags: plone

I am trying to change the Type Settings in Site Setup.  The default is Simple Publication Workflow.   When I tried to change it to Intranet Workflow or Community Workflow or any other workflow, I got this error:

```
    Traceback (innermost last):
      Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
      Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
      Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
      Module plone.app.controlpanel.types, line 165, in __call__
      Module zope.event, line 23, in notify
      Module zope.component.event, line 24, in dispatch
      Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
      Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
      Module zope.interface.adapter, line 583, in subscribers
      Module plone.app.discussion.browser.controlpanel, line 181, in notify_configuration_changed
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'forInterface'
```

Can anybody advise?

We are using plone 4.1

Thank you very much.

Cmgui

Comment: You can find nearly the same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810648/an-error-when-trying-to-change-image-workflow/7811105#7811105

Comment: Wow, that's nasty. Hopefully there's a updated 4.1 coming out soon to fix that!

Comment: yes, nasty.  thank you giacomo for the reference link.   i will see if it works.